# How to navigate to page using ui-sref in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'am working on a Ionic 2 mobile app project. I have a Login page and Signup page. I want to navigate to **Sign Up** page by clicking **'Create new account.'** (not a button) text in **Login** page. I found it can be done using `<a ui-sref></a>` but I don't know how to implement it. Help will be appreciated!

Comment: i think in ionic 2 you don't have ui-sref ...but you've to use in your ts files this.nav.push(Page1); https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/

Comment: so in your html call a function where you put this.nav.push(Page1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in Ionic 2. You need to create an event in your template, like the click event `(click)="goToLogin()"` and in your .ts file do this:

```
import { MyLoginPageName} from '../path/to/login/page/folder';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular'; //what you use to navigate

export class MyCurrentPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController){}

  goToLogin(){
    this.navCtrl.push(MyLoginPageName);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I made click event for `<a>` tag and it worked.

Comment: glad it helped :D